# How to insert a space before the 2nd capital letter of a string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have some data from a 3rd-party and one column is a concatenation of first and last name - but there is no space in between. My goal is to insert a space before the second capital letter, e.g:

```
some_name
-------------
AdamPeterson
JohnSmith
StevenMulroy
```

Would become:

```
some_name
-------------
Adam Peterson
John Smith
Steven Mulroy
```

I know that this isn't foolproof, but it's the best it's going to get with the source data that I have.

I need to do this in SQL rather than Excel etc - because the data is refreshed regularly on the database level, and is then handled by another system without first being exported.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What version of MySQL do you use? MySQL Version 8 and MariaDB 10.0.5+ have REGEXP_REPLACE() functions.

Comment: @O.Jones Sadly we're running 5.5.55 InnoDB.

Comment: Define "word". What about "LeonardodaVinci"?

Comment: @tadman I want to insert a space before the 2nd capital letter - irrespective of whether it's right or wrong (this is what I meant by "I know this isn't foolproof" `:)`) - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a general query for all MySQL 5.1+ versions pretty sure it will also run on MariaDB. 
The general idea is using a MySQL number generator to split the string into "tokens" and check the ascii range if the "token" is a capital letter or not

**Query**

```
SELECT 
   names.name   
 ,  INSERT (
       names.name 
     , LOCATE(
           SUBSTRING(names.name, number_generator.number, 1)  
         , names.name   
       )
     , 1
     , CONCAT(' ', SUBSTRING(names.name, number_generator.number, 1))
   ) AS changed_name
FROM (
  SELECT 
    @row := @row + 1 AS number 
  FROM (
    SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT   6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row1
  CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT 0 UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9
) row2
CROSS JOIN (
  SELECT @row := 0 
) init_user_params 
) AS number_generator
CROSS JOIN 
 names 
WHERE
   number_generator.number > 1
 AND
   ASCII(SUBSTRING(names.name, number_generator.number, 1)) BETWEEN 65 AND 90
```

**Result**

```
| name         | changed_name  |
| ------------ | ------------- |
| AdamPeterson | Adam Peterson |
| JohnSmith    | John Smith    |
| StevenMulroy | Steven Mulroy |
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNJ41Dt8bCdX1GKcUTX7jy/0)

**Note**

This query will not scale well on (very) large tables with millions or even billions of records because off the `CROSS JOIN`

Or you can use a tableless approach with

`CROSS JOIN 
 (
   SELECT 
    'AdamPeterson' AS name
   UNION 
   SELECT 
     'JohnSmith'
   UNION
   SELECT 'StevenMulroy'
 ) AS names`

see that [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNJ41Dt8bCdX1GKcUTX7jy/3)

Or use batches when you have big tables

`CROSS JOIN 
 (
   SELECT 
    name 
   FROM 
    names 
   WHERE
    id >= 1 AND id <= 2
   ORDER BY 
    names.id ASC

 ) AS names`

Why no `LIMIT`? 
`LIMIT` is slow when using it with large offset numbers like `LIMIT 1000000, 1000`. MySQL needs to fetch 1001000 records and drop 1000000 records again from a (disk in worst case scenario) temporary table

see that [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNJ41Dt8bCdX1GKcUTX7jy/2)

**Edited**

> it all looks like black magic to me! It is almost perfect - try the
>   names 'AlexLafferty' or 'LaurenAnderson'. Maybe an off-by-one bug or
>   something on the A? Thanks for all your help!

After a review i noticed that using `LOCATE(..)` in the `INSERT(..)` is pretty much redundant and can be removed to get it working properly.

So the patch is

```
SELECT 
    names.name   
 ,  INSERT (
       names.name 
     , number_generator.number
     , 1
     , CONCAT(' ', SUBSTRING(names.name, number_generator.number, 1))
   ) AS changed_name
```

see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rNJ41Dt8bCdX1GKcUTX7jy/4)

Comment: Nice work, thanks - it all looks like black magic to me! It is almost perfect - try the names 'AlexLafferty' or 'LaurenAnderson'. Maybe an off-by-one bug or something on the A? Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Thanks for the comment @DannyBeckett i've update mine answer with a patch.

Answer (score 3):

For Mysql 8

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST('JohnLexxxanon' as BINARY), '^([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)$', '$1 $2');
```

For MariaDb 10+

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(CAST('JohnLexxxanon' as BINARY), '^([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)$', '\\1 \\2');
```

Data is casted to binary to achieve case sensitivity.

This works for MySql 8 and MariaDb 10+

Comment: Unfortunately we're running InnoDB version 5.5.55, otherwise this looks like a great solution `:(` It's in production unfortunately too so upgrading it isn't possible atm. I don't suppose you have any alternative solutions at all please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you really sure $1, $2 etc works in MySql, i.e back referencing groups?

Comment: Strange, it will not work for me on MariaDb 10.3, is it some configuration that needs to be set? _Edit_ Tested on dbfiddle, it works on MySql 8 but **not** on MariaDb 10.3

Comment: can you try `'\\1 \\2'` for MariaDb, I edited my answer for clearity

Comment: Great, now it works. For some reason \\ didn't work for me earlier but I must have done some other mistake.

Comment: Note that for MySql the cast can be replaced with an `match_type` argument to REGEXP_REPLACE, in this case 'c' for case sensitive. `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('JohnLexxxanon', '^([A-Z][a-z]+)([A-Z][a-z]+)$', '$1 $2', 1, 1, 'c')`